# Wamp server and electron io

Tags: php, web-applications, wamp, electron

I've been trying to develop a desktop application using electron,i'm using php as server side language with wamp server,how we can package the application with a server and the database in an .exe file???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to package a webserver, PHP has its standalone internal webserver since PHP 5.4. Also, you can migrate your database to sqlite, then you don't need a database. The only thing you need is a standalone version of PHP, that you can download on php.net website.
For a working example of PHP application inside electron, see https://github.com/garak/electron-symfony

Comment: thank you very much sir,I liked using electron instead of php desktop for encrypting my code....